# Mingw64 shell's grep ignores -r option?

Tags: grep, mingw-w64

I'm trying to do a grep in Microsoft Windows, using the MINGW64 shell v4.4.23(1). (That's what the title bar says. I assume this means MingW-W64.)

I want to list all files in a specified directory tree that have a certain filename extension and do not contain a certain string.

With the current directory set to the top of the tree I entered

```
grep -r -L thestring *.theextension
```

It lists only files in the current directory, not the tree.

I tried some variations and determined that grep is simply ignoring the -r option. It ignores --recursive, too.

But when I enter `grep --help`, it lists both `-r` and `--recursive` as valid options, with the expected meaning.

Is this a bug in the shell, or am I doing something stupid?

Answer (score 0):

With `grep -r -L thestring *.theextension` you are telling grep to search recursively in any file or folder matching `*.theextension`. If you don't have any folders matching that you shouldn't expect it to go through any other folders. The `-L` flag doesn't mean it's going to look at anything not matching `*.theextension`, maybe that's what was confusing you...